# After IF statment is fired as True, from inside this code move to the Else part of the IF statement

Tags: if-statement, coding-style, implementation

I am curious to know one thing. Is it possible in .NET (or in any language that you might have faced to execute this scenario:

Pseudo code below:

```
if(statement)
  //do something
  //Because you calculated or read something else, **drop|go|navigate** to else part
  //(not necessarily error or exception)
  //rest of if-true code continues, but is not executed because you moved to else
else
 //do something in else part, code continues here and is executed till the end normally
end-if
```

Before you down vote me, I know this is a perfect try-throw-catch solvable implementation and this is how I address it for now.

Inside the if I don't need to throw an exception because in terms of logic and BI there is absolutely no exception.

I need to know if it is supported in .NET or any other language through the if declaration without throwing an exception or implementing it with try-catch.

With the simplest words I can find... my question is: Is it possible to execute the Else part of an if condition even if the if(true) is fired? Can I change my mind inside the if(true)?

Answer (score 0):

In some programming languages you can, using LABELS and GOTO

But understanding the problem would help finding a good solution. It seems an IF/ELSE is not what you want, why not using 2 ifs ? If you want to just go straight to the second option... Maybe close inside a function/method, and call whenever you need. Explain the problem better and maybe we can get a solution better :P

Comment: Gabriel, it is not a problem. I am trying to argue with logic. I am just curious if that behavior is present in any language and I will check the LABELS and GOTO that you said above. It is not a problem only trying to understand if such behavior is possible... changing the if(true) and moving to else even after the if is fired as true :)

Comment: then, this is a case thats usually an exception yes, as if/else would be the main course and else wont be fired when if is, based on the basic design on how programming went. The LABEL and GOTO is a bad pratice, old languages used that the most modern ones wont have it, while they might have the 'finally' so execute code even the if or else was/wasnt fired.

Comment: Gabriel might I ask you and example with Labels and Goto in any language you know? or a link or reference to such example?

Comment: hi Gabriel, I checked this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto, can you please send me an exact example in any programming language where you can do that behavior in order for me to test/see?